# Removing whitespace at bottom of a page when using a sticky image

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout where I am using `position: sticky` to place an image near the bottom right corner of the page (below a flex layout):

```css
.footer-logo {position: sticky; bottom: 50px; z-index: 100; margin: 50px; padding: 25px; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: green; float: right;}
.flex-container {height: 400px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; background-color: #f2f2f2; padding-top:20px; justify-content: center;}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container"></div>
<img class="footer-logo" src="https://placehold.it/100x100"></img>
```

The `img` sticks in the correct position, but below the `flex-container` there is whitespace which spans the full width of the page and is the same height as the `img` (including padding & margin).

How do I not display this whitespace whilst still retaining the correct positioning of the `img`?

Comment: Can you point out which white space you're talking about ?

Comment: Do you want it to be floating in the bottom right no matter what? You could use fixed positioning instead maybe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove it using negative margin equal to the height. That space is the space of the image since `position:sticky` will keep the element part of the flow:

```css
.footer-logo {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 50px;
  z-index: 100;
  padding: 25px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  float: right;
}

.flex-container {
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding-top: 20px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: -150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container"></div>
<img class="footer-logo" src="https://placehold.it/100x100">
```

Comment: this is the right answer, it's simple and kinda "dumb" (i rarely use negative margin as it feels cheap) but in this case, it's the proper way to do so as it will make the div swap from position: static/relative to the sticky fixed one, ty

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        .footer-logo {
            position: sticky;
            z-index: 100;
            padding: 25px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: green;
            float: right;
        }
        .flex-container {
            height: 400px;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: -150px;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container"></div>
    <img class="footer-logo" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="100x100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I just needed to use `position: fixed` with `bottom` and `right` also set:

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        .footer-logo {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 50px;
            right: 50px;
            z-index: 100;
            padding: 25px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: green;
        }
        .flex-container {
            height: 400px;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
            padding-top: 20px;
            margin-bottom: -150px;
            justify-content: center;
        }
```

```html
<div class="flex-container"></div>
    <img class="footer-logo" src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt="100x100" />
```